# Appending multiple children to an element

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html code

```
<div class="row clearfix" id="newline">
  <div class="col-sm-3" id="divTag">
    <input  type="text"  id="inputProdus">
  </div>
</div>

<button type="submit" name="action_maimulteproduse" id="newlinebutton">New Line</button>
```

I would like to add another input field but I would also like to add the div with id="divTag".

I have the following javascript code but I can only add the input tag and not the div with id "divTag"

```
var add = document.getElementById("newlinebutton");
        add.addEventListener('click', function(){
            var cloned=document.getElementById('inputProdus').cloneNode();
            cloned.value = '';
            document.getElementById('newline').appendChild(cloned).appendChild(cloned1);
        },false);
```

Comment: Can't you use `setAttribute()`?

Comment: Watch out for duplicate IDs. IDs must be unique.  Maybe use a class instead.

Comment: The input field is under multiple div's that have been set using the CSS. It would be vary hard to add all the attributes manually in there.

Comment: I have made sure that all IDs are unique. I have multiple entries using the same class so I would never get the correct one if I use the class.

Comment: could the deep attribute of [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) be an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** cloned1 is not defined.

**2.** In your code, you're only cloning the input not the div that's why you are only adding the input tag and not the div with id "divTag".

**3.** Don't clone an element with an id, at least change the id before you append the element.

**So what do you have to do?**

Remove the id's and use classes and then do what you want to do.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row clearfix" id="newline">
  <div class="col-sm-3" class="divTag">
    <input  type="text"  class="inputProdus">
  </div>
</div>

<button type="submit" name="action_maimulteproduse" id="newlinebutton">New Line</button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
var add = document.getElementById("newlinebutton");
add.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var element = document.querySelector('.divTag');
    var cloned = element.cloneNode();

var parent = element.parentElement.cloneNode();

cloned.value = '';

parent.appendChild(cloned);
document.getElementById('newline').appendChild(parent);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code resets the input's value, then places the input in a cloned version of the parent, then appends the parent to the `newline` element.

```
var add = document.getElementById("newlinebutton");
add.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var element = document.getElementById('inputProdus');
    var cloned = element.cloneNode();
    var parent = element.parentElement.cloneNode();

    cloned.value = '';

    parent.appendChild(cloned);
    document.getElementById('newline').appendChild(parent);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

an **ID** should only refer to one element, a **class** is used to categorize multiple elements, since your *divtag* is not only for one element, you should use class instead of div.

```
    <div class="row clearfix" id="newline">
  <div class="col-sm-3" class="divTag">
    <input  type="text"  id="inputProdus">
  </div>
</div>
```

You Javascript code has to be like the one in the previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

I usually recommend using a template element for cloning - in this case it's hidden by CSS. When cloning, we remove the template DIV's id, and add an unique id to the child input. I used simple counting, but you might want some other logic.

```js
var add = document.getElementById("newlinebutton");

add.addEventListener('click', function() {

  var clonedDiv = document.getElementById('divTemplate').cloneNode(true);

  clonedDiv.removeAttribute('id');

  let inputId = 'input-' + (document.getElementById('newline').childNodes.length - 1);

  clonedDiv.childNodes[1].setAttribute('id', inputId);
  document.getElementById('newline').appendChild(clonedDiv);

}, false);
```

```css
#divTemplate {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="divTemplate" class="col-sm-3">
  <input type="text" />
</div>

<div class="row clearfix" id="newline">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" id="input-1" />
  </div>
</div>

<button type="submit" name="action_maimulteproduse" id="newlinebutton">New Line</button>
```